# How do I access all the data in an excel cell? I need to import into MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime, import-from-excel

I have an Excel data file that has the date and time in a cell. The data stored in the cell (aka the data in the formula bar) is:

```
3/11/2016  5:27:36 PM
```

But the same cell displays

```
2016/03/11 17:27:37.653
```

I need to access the milliseconds, and for some reason that information isn't handled the same way. Excel can't work with it unless I copy it to Word and paste it back into Excel. How can I get the milliseconds into MATLAB? I will need to read dozens of these files.

My MATLAB code only consists of:

```
for i=1:5
    traverse_file=sprintf('traverse_s4r%d.xlsx',i);
    [num,text,both{i}]=xlsread(traverse_file);
end
```

This is what the Excel cells look like:

```
2016/03/11 17:27:19.213 0.000004
2016/03/11 17:27:35.813 -0.00002
2016/03/11 17:27:36.000 0.000015
```

This is what is contained in the cells:

```
3/11/2016  5:27:19 PM 0.000004
3/11/2016  5:27:36 PM -0.00002
3/11/2016  5:27:36 PM 0.000015
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, as I do not work with MATLAB, but the actual value stored in that cell will be the number of days and fractions of a day since 1/1/1900 (or 1/1/1904 if you are using that system).  For your displayed date, that value would be `42440.7275191319` which is accessible as the `.Value2` property of the Range object, or could be seen if you format the cell as `Number` with enough decimal places.

Comment: post the code you're using to read the excel file. Also a sample file would help.

Comment: @Amro I have added more information. Thanks

Comment: @RonRosenfeld +1 I took your comment and implemented it for MATLAB, by accessing the `.Value2` property just like you said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `xlsread` retrieves date/time fields as strings formatted according to the current system locale. The problem is that in most cases the fraction part of seconds is not displayed, which is lost when you import the file. There's a note at the end of [the documentation of `xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#moreabout) explaining this:

> `xlsread` imports formatted dates as strings (such as '10/31/96'), except in `basic` mode and on computers without Excel for Windows.

[Fortunately](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/169377), you can pass a [custom processing function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#inputarg_processFcn) in `xlsread` to get the raw unformatted values (this is only supported on Windows computers with Excel software installed). As @RonRosenfeld explained in the comments, Excel stores datetimes as [serial numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680) representing the fractional days since 00-January-1900:

> Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900, is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008, is serial number 39448 because it is 39,448 days after January 1, 1900.

You can get the unformatted values from COM/ActiveX using the `.Value2` property.

Note that MATLAB has it's own convention for storing [serial date numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) (as the fractional number of days since 00-January-0000). So once we load the raw serial numbers from Excel, we need to convert that to the convention used by MATLAB. With the [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#inputarg_dateType) class in MATLAB, the conversion is easy as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files.html).

---

Now that we have all that settled, here is the code to load your Excel files with full date/time precision:

```
function t = loadMyExcelFile(fnameXLSX, sheet)
    % read Excel sheet using our custom processing function to get the
    % raw dates without any formatting
    if nargin<2, sheet = 1; end
    [~,~,~,custom] = xlsread(fnameXLSX, sheet, '', '', @CustomProcessFcn);

    % convert excel dates to MATLAB datetime, also customize how
    % the datetime values are displayed (with full precision)
    dt = datetime(cell2mat(custom(:,1)), 'ConvertFrom','excel', ...
        'Format','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS');
    val = cell2mat(custom(:,2));

    % compute the milliseconds part alone
    ms = round(rem(dt.Second, 1) * 1000);

    % build and return results as a MATLAB table
    t = table(dt, val, ms);
end

function [data, V2] = CustomProcessFcn(data)
    V2 = data.Value2;
end
```

To verify the above import function, I created sample a Excel sheet with random dates and values (you can [download it here](http://filebin.ca/2bmKuECOw334/Book1.xlsx) if you want to follow along).

[image: excel_sheet]

(note: I changed the cell formatting of dates to custom `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` to see the milliseconds part).

Finally you can load the data and manipulate it however yo want:

```
>> t = loadMyExcelFile('Book1.xlsx')
t = 
                dt                  val      ms 
    __________________________    _______    ___
    2016-03-28 23:00:25.100877    0.31472    101
    2016-03-29 18:58:28.578988    0.72052    579
    2016-03-30 10:19:04.318113     0.3475    318
    2016-03-31 10:00:26.065898    0.76088     66
    2016-04-01 14:19:13.908256    0.89324    908
    2016-04-02 04:29:42.858488    0.49078    858
    2016-04-03 07:12:32.249770    0.26928    250
    2016-04-04 16:48:25.073809    0.31616     74
    2016-04-05 08:51:05.228647    0.77366    229
    2016-04-06 21:38:29.768989     1.2386    769
    2016-04-07 06:55:49.555229    0.89617    555
    2016-04-08 01:13:40.028169     1.3668     28
    2016-04-09 23:38:56.049314     1.8239     49
    2016-04-10 04:13:09.258885     1.8093    259
    2016-04-11 09:40:38.799400     2.1096    799
    2016-04-12 03:37:27.442933     1.7515    443
    2016-04-13 12:20:01.502968     1.6732    503
    2016-04-14 18:15:25.406924      2.089    407
    2016-04-15 14:46:10.802325     2.3812    802
    2016-04-16 02:58:43.615177     2.8407    615

>> plot(t.dt, t.val)
```

[image: datetime_plot]

Comment: I should mention that you need at least MATLAB R2014b to work with `datetime` objects. For older versions, you would use `datenum` instead (serial date numbers) or just plain old strings.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
doc datestr
```

if the following doesn't work. there is LOTS of support for manipulating dates/times in their myriad formats. avail yourself of these before killing yourself coming up with a custom solution.

```
time = datestr(text, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:MM:dd.fff')
[y,m,d,h,m,s] = datevec(time);
ms = s - floor(s);
```